# Autodesk.Forge : Design automation App Bundle not loaded

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

i'm working on this tutorial [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/appbundle/netcore) and also used the one on github [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation)

All works fine but the web app is not loading (in UI) the zip into "bundles" folder, but when i call /api/appbundles/ i got this

```
[
  "UpdateDWGParam",
  "UpdateIPTParam",
  "UpdateMAXParam",
  "UpdateRVTParam"
]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: This seems interesting, the UI uses same endpoint as /api/appbundles/, quick idea, did you debug into the code to see if any issues? Or maybe a refresh to see if help?

Comment: Hi thank you, i tryed debugging but nothing special, i thought that something was missing on js (who make the ui i think) then found that the filename was not spelled well ^^ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the js file is loaded correctly, check the file name and path.